# How do I keep a JavaScript array from filling on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I am trying to populate an array through JQuery based on option values in multiple select element. For each select element, I want the array to be recreated as an empty array and filled again with new options. However, when I check the array in the console, it seems to be already full with items from each select element as soon as the page loads.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#reportForm select').each(function(){
        var optionValues=[];
        console.log(optionValues);
        $('option').each(function(){
           if($.inArray(this.value, optionValues) >-1){
               $(this).remove()
           }else{
              optionValues.push(this.value);
                }
           });
       });
    });
```

On the first console.log() the array should have zero elements in it, however it has over 200.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is that *all your code*? That makes zero sense.

Comment: @Li357 you're not helping by saying 'that makes zero sense' you can say 'please provide all your code so we can help you better' or something that will guide him to provide more context/details

Comment: The code is in a es6 template string. perhaps a copy and paste error? It won't execute as it is.

Comment: @Li357 it is all the JS code relevant to this issue. I am new to asking questions on StackOverflow, apologies for not providing enough.

Comment: @PatrickCoyle If you assign `optionValues` to an empty array then immediately log it, it will stay empty. And it's not  a scoping issue since `var` is function-scoped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your loop is traversing for all options on the page. You have to find the options in a select drop down. So use `$(this).find('option')` in place of `$('option')` like,

```
$('#reportForm select').each(function(){
    var optionValues=[];
    console.log(optionValues);
    $(this).find('option').each(function(){ // $(this).find will only find options inside the current select
       if($.inArray(this.value, optionValues) >-1){
           $(this).remove()
       } else {
          optionValues.push(this.value);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @PatrickCoyle put a tick to the answer so others can understand that the OPs got the required answer of the question.

Comment: I did :) I just had to wait for the timer.